# have multiple input_type in Option?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I want to create a command that will show you every message from a member or all messages for every user with one role. my command looks like this at the moment

```
    @slash_command(name='messages', description='Get messages.', guild_ids = [933307298011562006])
    async def messages(self, ctx, user : Option(discord.Member, "Get the Messages from a User or a Role.", required = True)):
```

and I want that the user can enter either a member or a Role within this one Command. If that is Possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just did it with this:

```
    @slash_command(name='messages', description='Get messages.', guild_ids = [933307298011562006])
    async def messages(self, ctx, user : Option(discord.Member, "type in the User", required = False), role : Option(discord.Role, "type in the Role.", required = False)):
```

Not exactly what I wanted, but It works

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [example from the pycord GitHub](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/app_commands/slash_options.py), you should be able to achieve your desired result with something like this (full disclosure: I have **not** tested this):

```py
@slash_command(name='messages', description='Get messages.', guild_ids = [933307298011562006])
async def messages(self, ctx, user : Option([discord.Member, discord.Role], "Get the Messages from a User or a Role.", required = True)):
```

On the other hand, there also is a specific "Mentionable" [slash command option type](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.SlashCommandOptionType.mentionable) that provides you with users and roles directly, so the following should also work:

```py
@slash_command(name='messages', description='Get messages.', guild_ids = [933307298011562006])
async def messages(self, ctx, user : Option(discord.SlashCommandOptionType.mentionable, "Get the Messages from a User or a Role.", required = True)):
```